# Visual Studio Command Prompt C/C++ Compiling Error " Error Code C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';' "

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, syntax, compiler-errors

I'm new to writing code and have spent hours trying to solve this error.
The script is for a memory scanner. Here is the code I have. The error is in 
line 147. It keeps giving me error C2143 missing ')' before ' ; ' ...

```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define IS_IN_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] & (1<<((offset)%8)));
  #define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~ (1<<((offset)%8));


  typedef struct MEMBLOCK
  {
      HANDLE hProc;
      unsigned char *addr;
      int size;
      unsigned char *buffer;

      unsigned char *searchmask;
      int matches;
      int data_size;

      struct MEMBLOCK *next;
  }MEMBLOCK;

  typedef enum 
  {
      COND_UNCONDITIONAL,
      COND_EQUALS,

      COND_INCREASED,
      COND_DECREASED,
  }SEARCH_CONDITION;


  MEMBLOCK* create_memblock (HANDLE hProc, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION *meminfo, int data_size)
  {
      MEMBLOCK *mb = malloc (sizeof(MEMBLOCK));

      if (mb)
      {
          mb->hProc = hProc;
          mb->addr = meminfo->BaseAddress;
          mb->size = meminfo->RegionSize;
          mb->buffer = malloc (meminfo->RegionSize);
          mb->searchmask = malloc (meminfo->RegionSize/8);
          memset (mb->searchmask, 0xff, meminfo->RegionSize/8);
          mb->matches = meminfo->RegionSize;
          mb->data_size = data_size;
          mb->next = NULL;
      }

      return mb;
  }

  void free_memblock (MEMBLOCK *mb)
  {
      if (mb)
      {
          if (mb->buffer);
          {
              free (mb->buffer);
          }

          if (mb->searchmask)
          {
              free (mb->searchmask);
          }

          free (mb);
      }
  }



  void update_memblock (MEMBLOCK *mb, SEARCH_CONDITION condition, unsigned int val)
  {
      static unsigned char tempbuf[128*1024];
      unsigned int bytes_left;
      unsigned int total_read;
      unsigned int bytes_to_read;
      unsigned int bytes_read;

      if (mb->matches > 0)
      { 
          bytes_left = mb->size;
          total_read = 0;
          mb->matches = 0;

          while (bytes_left)
          {
              bytes_to_read = (bytes_left > sizeof(tempbuf)) ? sizeof(tempbuf) :   bytes_left;
        ReadProcessMemory (mb->hProc, mb->addr + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_to_read, (DWORD*)&bytes_read);
        if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read) break;

        if (condition == COND_UNCONDITIONAL)
        {
            memset (mb->searchmask + (total_read/8), 0xff, bytes_read/8);
            mb->matches += bytes_read;
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned int offset;

            for (offset = 0; offset < bytes_read; offset += mb->data_size)
            {
                if IS_IN_SEARCH(mb,(total_read+offset)) 
                {
                    BOOL is_match = FALSE;
                    unsigned int temp_val;
                    unsigned int prev_val = 0;

                    switch (mb->data_size)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            temp_val = tempbuf[offset];
                            prev_val = *((unsigned char*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            temp_val = *((unsigned short*)&tempbuf[offset]);
                            prev_val = *((unsigned short*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                        default:
                            temp_val = *((unsigned int*)&tempbuf[offset]);
                            prev_val = *((unsigned int*)&mb->buffer[total_read+offset]);
                            break;                          
                    }

                    switch (condition)
                    {
                        case COND_EQUALS:
                            is_match = (temp_val == val);
                            break;
                        case COND_INCREASED:
                            is_match = (temp_val > prev_val);
                            break;
                        case COND_DECREASED:
                            is_match = (temp_val < prev_val);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;                     
                    }

                    if  (is_match)
                    {
                        mb->matches++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
      147===*?      REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,(total_read+offset));   ?*===147  
                    }          
                }
            }          
        }

        memcpy (mb->buffer + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_read);

        bytes_left -= bytes_read;
        total_read += bytes_read;   
   }

    mb->size = total_read;  
}
  } 

  MEMBLOCK* create_scan (unsigned int pid, int data_size)
  {
      MEMBLOCK *mb_list = NULL;
      MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
      unsigned char *addr = 0;

      HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

      if (hProc)
      {
          while (1)
          {
              if (VirtualQueryEx (hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)) == 0)
              {
                  break;
              }
  #define WRITABLE (PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY)
              if ((meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT) && (meminfo.Protect & WRITABLE)) 
              {          
                 MEMBLOCK *mb = create_memblock (hProc, &meminfo, data_size);
                  if (mb)
                  {                 
                      mb->next = mb_list;
                      mb_list = mb;
                  }
              }
              addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;
          }
      }

      return mb_list;
  }


  void free_scan (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
  {
      CloseHandle (mb_list->hProc);

      while (mb_list)
      {
          MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
          mb_list = mb_list->next;
          free_memblock (mb);
      }
  }

  void update_scan (MEMBLOCK *mb_list, SEARCH_CONDITION condition, unsigned int val)
 {
      MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
      while (mb)
      {
          update_memblock (mb, condition, val);
          mb = mb->next;
      }
 }
 void dump_scan_info (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
 {
 MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;

      while (mb) 
      {
          int i;
          printf ("0x%08x %d\r\n", mb->addr, mb->size);

          for (i = 0; i < mb->size; i++)
          {
              printf ("%02x", mb->buffer[i]);
          }
          printf ("\r\n");

          mb = mb->next;

      }
  }


  void poke (HANDLE hProc, int data_size, unsigned int addr, unsigned int val)
  {
      if (WriteProcessMemory (hProc, (void*)addr, &val, data_size, NULL) == 0)
      {
          printf ("poke failed\r\n");
      }
  }

  unsigned int peek (HANDLE hProc, int data_size, unsigned int addr)
  {
      unsigned int val = 0;

      if  (ReadProcessMemory (hProc, (void*)addr, &val, data_size, NULL) == 0)
      {
          printf ("peek failed\r\n");
      }

      return val;   
  }


  void print_matches (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
  {
      unsigned int offset;
      MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;

      while (mb)
      {
          for (offset = 0; offset < mb->size; offset += mb->data_size)
          {
              if  IS_IN_SEARCH(mb,offset)
              {
                  unsigned int val = peek (mb->hProc, mb->data_size, (unsigned int)mb->addr + offset); 
                  printf ("0x%08x: 0x%08x (%d) \r\n", mb->addr + offset, val, val);    
              }         
          }
          mb = mb->next;
      }
  }


  int get_match_count (MEMBLOCK *mb_list)
  {
      MEMBLOCK *mb = mb_list;
      int count = 0;

      while (mb)
      {
          count += mb->matches;
          mb = mb->next;
      }

      return count;
  }


  unsigned int str2int (char *s)
  {
      int base = 10;

      if (s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x')
      {
          base = 16;
          s += 2;
      }

      return strtoul (s, NULL, base);
  }


  MEMBLOCK* ui_new_scan(void)
  {
      MEMBLOCK *scan = NULL;
      DWORD pid;
      int data_size;
      unsigned int start_val;
      SEARCH_CONDITION start_cond;
      char s[20];

      while(1)
      {
          printf ("\r\nEnter the pid: ");
          fgets (s,sizeof(s),stdin);
          pid = str2int (s);
          printf ("\r\nEnter the data size: ");
          fgets (s,sizeof(s),stdin);
          data_size = str2int (s);
          printf ("\r\nEnter the start value, or 'u' for unknown: ");
          fgets (s,sizeof(s),stdin);
          if (s[0] == 'u')
          {
              start_cond = COND_UNCONDITIONAL;
              start_val = 0;
          }
          else
          {
              start_cond = COND_EQUALS;
              start_val = str2int (s);      
          }

          scan = create_scan (pid, data_size);
          if (scan) break;
          print ("\r\nInvalid scan");
      }

      update_scan (scan, start_cond, start_val);
      printf ("\r\n%d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));

      return scan;
  }


  void ui_poke (HANDLE hProc, int data_size)
  {
      unsigned int addr;
      unsigned int val;
      char s[20];

      printf ("Enter the address: ");
      fgets (s,sizeof(s),stdin);
      addr = str2int (s);

      printf ("\r\nEnter the value: ");
      fgets (s,sizeof(s),stdin);
      val = str2int (s);
      printf ("\r\n");

      poke (hProc, data_size, addr, val);
  }


  void ui_run_scan(void)
  {
      unsigned int val;
      char s[20];
      MEMBLOCK *scan;

      scan = ui_new_scan();

      while (1)
      {
          printf ("\r\nEnter the next value or");
          printf ("\r\n[i] increased");
          printf ("\r\n[d] decreased");
          printf ("\r\n[m] print matches");
          printf ("\r\n[p] poke address");
          printf ("\r\n[n] new scan");
          printf ("\r\n[q] quit\r\n");

          fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);
          printf ("\r\n");

          switch (s[0])
          {
              case 'i':
                  update_scan (scan, COND_INCREASED, 0);
                 printf ("%d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
                 break;
              case 'd':
                  update_scan (scan, COND_DECREASED, 0);
                  printf ("%d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
                  break;
              case 'm':
                  print_matches (scan);
                  break;
              case 'p':
                  ui_poke (scan->hProc, scan->data_size);
                  break;
              case 'n':
                  free_scan (scan);
                  scan = ui_new_scan();
                  break;
              case 'q':
                  free_scan (scan);
                  return;
              default:
                  val = str2int (s);
                  update_scan (scan, COND_EQUALS, val);
                  printf ("%d matches found\r\n", get_match_count(scan));
                  break;                
          }
      }
  }



  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      ui_run_scan();        
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I haven't gone through your entire code yet but you have a semicolon after your `if` in `free_memblock` -----> `if (mb->buffer); { ... }` Probably not what you wanted

Comment: @Marlon - Well spotted! This too is a mistake, although I think it will lead to a subtle logic error (always freeing the buffer), rather than causing the problem the OP describes.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I know it wasn't causing the problem the OP described, that's why I made it a comment! (as opposed to an answer) Anyways, it will lead to lots of UB down the road if that `;` stays there.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
#define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,offset) \
          (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~ (1<<((offset)%8));
```

to

```
#define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,offset) \
          (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~ (1<<((offset)%8)))
```

specifically, there is a missing closing parenthesis.

Also, the semicolons are not needed and typically omitted. This type of error is one reason we often favor inline functions over macros :)

Comment: Even specifying `inline` is becoming a thing of the past. Code size is so important to the cache that one should only really specify `static`.

Comment: @Dave which compiler+architecture would produce a smaller body for `update_memblock` with `REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH` as an out of line function?

Comment: the compiler can still inline a static function if it chooses. But if the compiler doesn't think it's a good idea; don't try to convince it so. It's a form of micro-optimization

Comment: @Dave Every C/C++ compiler that I use can benefit from the engineer's guidance. If you don't trust the engineer to give the right guidance, perhaps you should add that to *your* answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #define IS_IN_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] & (1<<((offset)%8)));
 #define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~ (1<<((offset)%8));
```

Should be

```
 #define IS_IN_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] & (1<<((offset)%8)))
 #define REMOVE_FROM_SEARCH(mb,offset) (mb->searchmask[(offset)/8] &= ~ (1<<((offset)%8))
```

Or, better yet, make them functions to avoid the terrible macro pitfalls:

```
 static int is_in_search(MEMBLOCK* mb, unsigned int offset){
     return mb->searchmask[offset/8] & (1<<(offset%8));
 }
 static void remove_from_search(MEMBLOCK *mb, unsigned int offset){
     mb->searchmask[offset/8] &= ~ (1<<(offset%8));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#define`s don't have a `;` at the end. It's treated as an error by the compiler.

Comment: Not until you invoke the macro -- and possibly not even then, depending on the context.